# How do I check what function a key is binded to in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The question is pretty self-explanatory. I'm trying to make a settings menu in my Tkinter app, and the way I'm doing it, is that it gets all currently packed and placed objects and saves them, unpacks/unplaces them, and then packs/places them back later once the settings are closed. I'm trying to do the same thing for key binds, and I've found a way to list all currently bound keys:

```
for bind in self.bind():
    print(bind)
```

However, it only lists the keys, not what function they are bound to. I can't re-bind them later if the program doesn't know what function to bind them to. Here's my code below, if it makes more sense:

```
def settings(self):
    self.settings_close = not self.settings_close if self.settings_close!=None else False
    if self.settings_close:
        for place in self.all_slaves["place"].keys():
            place.place(**self.all_slaves["place"][place])
        for pack in self.all_slaves["pack"].keys():
            pack.pack(**self.all_slaves["pack"][pack])
        for bind in self.all_slaves["bind"].keys():
            self.bind(bind, self.all_slaves["bind"][bind]) # I need the function for this part
        return
    
    self.bind("<Escape>", lambda s=None: self.settings())
    
    self.all_slaves = {
        "place": {},
        "pack": {},
        "bind": {}
    }
    for place in self.place_slaves():
        if place not in [self.button_main_menu, self.button_settings]:
            self.all_slaves["place"][place] = place.place_info()
            place.place_forget()
    for pack in self.pack_slaves():
        self.all_slaves["pack"][pack] = pack.pack_info()
        pack.pack_forget()
    for bind in self.bind():
        self.all_slaves["bind"][bind] = "bind function" # How do I get the function?
        self.unbind(bind)
```

Ideally, something similar to the pack_info and place_info functions, but for the function that is bound to the keys.

Comment: Just because you unpack a widget doesn't mean the binding goes away. It would still have all of the bindings. It's not clear why you need to save and restore the bindings.

Comment: I'm talking about the bindings to the window. I bind <Escape> for example, to open settings. But I have a few more binds that do things in specific areas of my app, and I'd like to remove the bindings (with self.unbind(key)) and then add them back later, with the same function.